# error: The following required arguments were not provided: <path>

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I am following the [Rust getting started guide](https://www.rust-lang.org/learn/get-started). I'm in the "Generating a new project" section attempting to generate a "Hello, world!" project by running `cargo new`.

[image]

However, after running `cargo new` I get the following error.

```
❯ cargo new
error: The following required arguments were not provided:
    <path>

USAGE:
    cargo new [OPTIONS] <path>

For more information try --help
```

I am running the command in the `/hello-rust` directory as instructed. I've also attempted to run the command in the `/hello-rust/src` directory with the same result.

What path do I need to include in my command?

Comment: I've created a design bug report and requested that Rust improve this documentation: https://github.com/rust-lang/www.rust-lang.org/issues/1285.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't tell you to run `cargo new`. It tells you to run `cargo new hello-rust`. Look further up in your screenshot. The part you've circled just explains what the `cargo new` command does. If you look at its manpage, you'll see that it is indeed meant to be invoked as `cargo new [OPTIONS] PATH`.

Comment: Thank you. I'll submit a design bug report to https://github.com/rust-lang/www.rust-lang.org. That was confusing and hard to follow. The docs don't indicate that that section is simply an explanation.

Comment: Well, that's a matter of debate, and not suited for SO, but it also doesn't at all indicate that it is anything *but* simply an explanation.